# How to mount a drbd/gfs logical volume from Xen VM?

Tags: xen, lvm, drbd, gfs

Any hint on how to do this for primary/primary? I have drbd and gfs running ok, I can see the logical volume from the DomU but dont know how to mount it. Should I install gfs on DomU and mount???

Thanks

Cris

Answer (score 1):

Is DRBD running on Dom0 or on the DomU?

If DRBD is running on Dom0 then you want to mount the block device within the DomU's then format with GFS. Within the DomU's it's be something like /dev/xbd[n]

If DRBD is running within the DomU's then you should be able to format the block device as GFS on the DomU's but  it's be called something like /dev/drbd[n]

I am assuming that you have the Xen root partition on a separate device and the gfs partition will be an additional mount point?